# SQL Server : how to apply sorting by a field that consists of multiple values divided in two logical groups

Tags: sql-server

The problem is following:

I have to retrieve and sort records which are logically separated in two groups: Active (2,1) and Inactive (0).

The problem is that `Active` group consists of two values, the `Inactive` of one value and sorting has to be applied to logical groups not field values.

E.g.

```
Product Product_Description Status Priority 
"Soap" "Nice soap" 2 A 
"Sponge" "Hard sponge" 1 B 
"Water" "It comes there too" 0 A 
"Wind" "I don't know how it got here" 0 B 
"Toothbrush" "It's more logical" 2 B
```

So the query should order records by Status and Priority. But the `Status` column consists of 3 values separated logically in two groups (2,1) and (0).

Query should return:

```
"Soap" 2 A 
"Toothbrush" 2 B 
"Sponge" 1 B
"Water" 0 A 
"Wind" 0 B
```

- I cannot change table structure
- The only idea which came to mind is by using Union all and dividing the query into two parts. But maybe there is a nicer way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group 2 and 1 together, separate from 0 you can use

```
 order by sign(status), priority
```

Comment: Wow! That's a great idea! Thanks!

Just checked - it works perfectly!